# Selecting all XML elements and their values dynamically using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following code which dynamically selects all of the distinct element names, however; I also want to see the values for these elements. How can I do this using LINQ? I am open to doing it other ways as well.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
 foreach (var name in doc.Descendants("QueryResults").Elements()
                .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
   foreach (var name in doc.Descendants("QueryResults").Elements()
                .Select(x => new {Name = x.Name, Value = e.Value}).Distinct())
   {


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted query is differnt then the original one because it changes how `Distinct` works because it no longer compares only `Name` but also `Value`. If you want to see which names have which values you need to use `GroupBy` on the `Name` and get the `Value` for each item.

```
var results =
    doc
        .Descendants("QueryResults")
        .Elements()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name, (name, items) => new
        {
            Name = name,
            Values = items.Select(x => x.Value)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just use `name.Value`, which is a string property of `XElement`.